# Choropleth map in html

Tags: javascript, html, d3

I am making a choropleth map of population estimate by counties in United States. I am almost done but the problem is a few counties have population count in seven figures and they are the ones that are not being filled. Can somebody help me fix that? I think something's wrong with this part of the code.

```
var color = d3.scaleThreshold()
.domain(d3.range(2,10).map(function(d) { return d * 1000; }))
.range(d3.schemeReds[9]);
```

Here's a link to my Gist on Github 
https://gist.github.com/sabeehtaqi/3c680626970a66ad63058b08f2a042a4

Comment: Disclaimer, I don't know d3 or javascript, but just looking at your block of code, my guess is that you need to change the part of the code that multiplies d by 1000.  Change it to: `return d * 10000` or `return d * 100000`. That might include the counties with the larger populations.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response @Fezter but that just changes the color range of the population, that still doesnt include those counties.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE! As a new user please take the [tour] to learn about our focused Q&A format.  Here you've added a comment in the space reserved for answers to the question.  Please respond to comments either in comments, or, if you are providing more information, as an edit to your question.

Comment: I have converted your non-answer to a comment.

Comment: What about this part of your code? `var x = d3.scaleLinear()
    .domain([0, 10000])
    .rangeRound([650, 1000]); ` on lines 16-18? Is the domain large enough?

Comment: @Fezter
Changing the domain in this part of the code just changes my legend.

Comment: Is this question solved? I can see that you added a regexp to your code and that the gist is working.